# how to include reference in JSFIDDLE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jsfiddle

Bit of a beginner at using JSFiddle...trying to recreate an issue in my code. Unsure how to include the correct reference though. For My code I am using:

```
    <link href="/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/css/start/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So my Q being how do I include these files in JSFiddle. Cant seem to find them from the drop down?

Thanks again

Comment: type `cdn url` at `External Resources`. And if just `jquery-ui`, choose `jquery-compact(edge)` at `Frameworks & Extensions` then it'll let you choose.

Comment: @ArunPJohny The issue here is that the files the OP is trying to link are custom builds of the jQueryUI library, so they will not be publicly hosted (unless he has already published his site). Also, the links in your fiddles external references use the relative paths provided above, so will never work.

Comment: thanks for the help guys....still cant get it working...if you seem my attempt https://jsfiddle.net/j73vpk1m/2/ does anyone know what I am doing wrong. popup should only display when 'create layer' button is clicked. the popUp should contain 3 radio button clicks with images attached to them and a 'next' button

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the external resource part. JSFiddle automatically identifies it as JS or CSS based on the extension:

[image]

**Note:** This will only work if the files are publicly available online. If they're only on your local machine, this feature won't work for you.

If you wanna upload your local file, you can use [Gists](https://gist.github.com/) and put your code in it. Then you can use [RawGit](https://rawgit.com/) to get the working URL and add it there, as usual.

[image]

Comment: Note this will only work if the files are publicly available online. If they're only on your local machine, this feature won't work for you.

Comment: If you mean you updated with those URLs, you may want to check them again.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan What crap! `:(` Updated the answer.

Comment: @PraveenKumar thanks for the help dude...Tried what you suggested when I add the external resources to JSFIDDLE an 'x' as added below the external resource '+' sign, but no mention of the file. I can click the 'x' removing it which I guess means moving the file from reference,...so are they not being added correctly as this doesnt work?

Comment: Er... @John Isn't that a new question you are supposed to ask?

Comment: @PraveenKumar guess so just thought you might know

Comment: @John Yes, you need to clarify too. I guess I can help. But please accept this answer, come out of this question, as this is solved, and ask a fresh question! `:)`